# Input field values duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, input, constructor

I am a first-time poster, so I don't know the best way to write about the problem. I will try to make it as clear as possible.
I am trying to do TODOLISt app. My purpose is to add items on click and display them in a table below. However, items keep stacking on top off each other. For example: if I add one task, press adds it returns that task. Problem acquires then the second one is added, it returns me a first task and the second one instead of just the second one. How can I get just the second one?

In the image link below i have saved to tasks, but got three outputs.

![Text] (https://ibb.co/S7N31Cx);

HTML

```
  <form>
        <div>
            <label for="todo-date">Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="todo-date" id="todo-date">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="todo-task">Task</label>
            <input type="text" class="todo-input" id="todo-task">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="todo-responsible">Who is responsible</label>
            <input type="text" class="todo-responsible" id="todo-responsible">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="todo-button" id="todo-button">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
        </button>
        </div>
    
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Responsible</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tbl-result" class="tblResult">
        <!--<td><input id="addClient" type="button" value="add" onclick="addClient()" /></td>
        <td><input id="viewClient" type="button" value="show" onclick="viewClient()" /></td> -->
        <tr></tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const toDoInput = document.getElementById('todo-task');
const toDoResp = document.getElementById('todo-responsible');
const toDoButton = document.getElementById('todo-button');
const tblResult = document.getElementById('tbl-result');
const toDoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
const filterOption = document.querySelector('.filter-todo');

// Event listeners
toDoButton.addEventListener('click', addToDo);
// Functions


// Class and Constructor



class clsTask {
    constructor (toDoDate, toDoInput, toDoResp) {
        this.toDoDate = toDoDate;
        this.toDoInput = toDoInput;
        this.toDoResp = toDoResp;
    }
}

let tasks = [];

function addToDo (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let task = new clsTask(toDoDate.value, toDoInput.value, toDoResp.value);

    tasks.push(task);
    toDoDate.value = "";
    toDoInput.value = "";
    toDoResp.value = "";

        for (let i=0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tblResult.appendChild(tr);
            tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td").appendChild(document.createTextNode(tasks[i].toDoDate)));
            tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td").appendChild(document.createTextNode(tasks[i].toDoInput)));
            tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td").appendChild(document.createTextNode(tasks[i].toDoResp)));
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to this line:

```
let tasks = [];
```

its scope is causing this to happen. so when you first push the element, it persists it as its not being reset or destroyed. so each time you push it will also have previous records hence causing duplications.

**SOLUTION:**
simple delete and move the mentioned line inside the `addToDo` function.

```
function addToDo (event) {
    //...
    let tasks = [];
    //...
}
```